# What is the repeated icon on the Quacks of Quedlinburg bonus dice?

Tags: quacks

I'm trying to use probability to calculate an optimal strategy for Quacks, but my copy is at another house. I know that the bonus dice has five symbols (1VP,2VP,Orange,Ruby,Drop) with one repeated. Can somebody tell me which one?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The Quacks of Quedlinburg bonus dice repeated icon is the 1 Victory Point icon. The faces of the die include:

- (2x) The player receives 1 victory point.
- The player receives 2 victory points.
- The player receives 1 ruby.
- The player can move their droplet 1 space.
- The player receives 1 orange pumpkin chip in their bag.